# Android WebView with HTML button and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

In an Android app using a WebView, I need to load a simple HTML file that includes HTML buttons and JavaScript code that must be executed when the user clicks the buttons. After a lot of reading, I can get the HTML to load in the WebView, but I can't get the HTML buttons to execute any JavaScript code. Here is the code that I have written.

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.byui.cit360.webviewwithjs.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package edu.byui.cit360.webviewwithjs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/first.html");
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

first.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fuel Efficiency</title>
    <script>
        function mpg() {
            var dist = parseFloat(document.getElementById('distance').value);
            var vol = parseFloat(document.getElementById('volume').value);
            var mpg = dist / vol;
            document.getElementById('volume').innerHTML = mpg;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Fuel Efficiency</h3>
    Distance <input type="number" id="distance" size="4"><br>
    Volume <input type="number" id="volume" size="4"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="mpg();">Fuel Efficiency</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter what JavaScript I put into the HTML button's onclick attribute, the WebView doesn't seem to execute it. I even tried: onclick="alert('Hello')" and still got nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aargh! Stupid mistake in my JavaScript code. This line

```
document.getElementById('volume').innerHTML = mpg;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = mpg;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set up your webview settings before triggering loadUrl-method:

```
    WebView view =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/first.html");
```